# Why my firebase update profilePhoto and coverPhoto when i just want to update profilePhoto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```
 const handleUpdateProfilePhoto = () => {
   if (photo == "") return;
   if (whichOne === "profile") {
     const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${photo}`);
     const uploadImage = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, photo);
     uploadImage.on(
       "state_changed",
       () => {},
       (error) => console.log(error),
       async () => {
         await getDownloadURL(uploadImage.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
           updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.id), {
             ...user,
             profilePhoto: url,
           });
         });
       }
     );
   }
   setUpdateProfileCoverPhoto("");
 };
```

I want to update only profilePhoto of the spacific user. but it update also the coverPhoto which i don't want

Comment: Where does the variable `user` come from?

Comment: try updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.id), {profilePhoto: url}).

Comment: I tried it, still do the same